# Laravel Jetstream - Navigation - Passing route name data to :active navigation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

In my `navigation-dropdown.blade.php` (from [Laravel Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/)), I have:

```
        <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>

        <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="/purchases" :active="request()->routeIs('purchases.index')">
            {{ __('Purchases') }}
        </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>                       

        <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="/debug" :active="request()->routeIs('debug')">
            {{ __('Debug') }}
        </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
```

In my `routes/web.php`, I have:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->resource('purchases','App\Http\Controllers\PurchaseController')->name('*', 'purchases');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/debug', [DebugController::class, 'index'])->name('debug');
```

I visit `/purchases` and `:isActive` does not set, but when I visit `/debug`, it does. In other words, appending `->name('debug')` to the route adds an underline to the 'Debug' when you are on the `/debug` view as expected.

However, appending `->name('purchases')` to the resource route causes an exception about not enough parameters. Calling `->name('*', 'purchases')` throws no exception but does nothing (there is no underline on this navigation item).

Whilst on the `/debug` view, you see:

[image: Screenshot of navigation with Debug underlined]

Whilst on the `/purchases` view, you see no underline:

[image: Missing underline on navigation item]

How do I fix this? I have also tried:

```
        <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="/purchases" :active="request()->routeIs('purchases')">
            {{ __('Purchases') }}
        </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
```

Answer (score 3):

i would use the route-name in href="":

```
<x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{route('purchases.index')}}" :active="request()->routeIs('purchases.index')">
    {{ __('Purchases') }}
</x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
```

also i would check active with a wildcard (*) to ensure it is active while your on another site like 'purchases.edit':

```
<x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{route('purchases.index')}}" :active="request()->routeIs('purchases.*')">
    {{ __('Purchases') }}
</x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
```

in general is a good idea to protect the routes with a middleware group so you dont have to add the middleware to each route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function(){
    Route::resource('purchases', PurchaseController::class); //resources don't need manual name
    Route::get('/debug', [DebugController::class, 'index'])->name('debug');
});
```

*dont forget

```
use 'App\Http\Controllers\PurchaseController';
```

in your route file or use full qualified name in Route:

```
Route::resource('purchases', App\Http\Controllers\PurchaseController::class);
```